# How to install libcurl for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c++, curl, windows-phone-8, libcurl

I would like to use libcurl in my windows phone 8 c++ project, has anyone done this yet, and if so please share details on what was necessary as I have tried but not had any success.

I would like to use libcurl, as I'd rather not have separate code bases for android and ios which both seem to support it.

Answer (score 5):

Libcurl runs just fine on Windows Phone. Not sure where everyone is getting information that WP8 doesn't have sockets, because it does.

We use libcurl in a shared library, including in apps approved by Microsoft in the store.

Here is my github repo containing a ready to go VS12 solution:

https://github.com/jneidlinger/libcurlwp8

Answer (score 0):

Currently libcurl does not support Windows Phone. Seems unlikely to in near term due to lack of BSD sockets in the Windows Phone 8 SDK. We recoded our HTTP layer to use native Microsoft XMLHTTP. Note there are a few benefits to this: the OS knows how to use User defined proxies (especially passworded ones), and networking libraries discovery can be better with native (when to turn on the hardware, reachability etc).

Comment: I have curl running on wp8 via a dynamic library, I had to make some minmal changes to the source and I have only enabled http plugin, wp8 supports sockets via winsock2, openssl is also working well too, I forgot to answer my own question, I need to send the files to the curl team, as Im sure others will surely find it useful including yourself